# Android EditText context menu style

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, android-contextmenu

I use my own style in my app.

```
<style name="My" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_text_default</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_hint</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_bg_window</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/My.ListView</item>
        <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/My.ListSeparator</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/My.Checkbox</item>
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/My.RadioButton</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/color_bg_window</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/color_bg_window</item>
        <item name="android:colorForegroundInverse">@color/color_bg_window</item>
</style>
```

App looks like fine, but on devices with Android 2 EditText context menu looks like bad (text is not visible)!

[image]

I know, that I can change Dialog style using ContextThemeWrapper whth default device theme, but I can not pass wrapped context to EditText context menu!

How can I change this dialog style?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own activity which will display as an popup and you can customize your popup activity. Just you have to change your activity theme as popup in your menifest.

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayNotesPopup"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        </activity>
```

You can customize this activity as popup and you can do anything with it you wants.
I hope this may solve your problem